# Laravel 5 - como conectar vários databases ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel-5

Já pesquisei em vários lugares, e todos eles acabam levando a [esse link](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections). Porém não consegui funcionar usando os métodos dados no link.

O problema: tenho 3 bancos configurados em config/database.php: "principal", "banco-1" e "financeiro", e preciso usar todos os 3 no mesmo controller. O sistema só acessa um deles, os outros 2 só servem para validações na hora do login, como verificação financeira e outros.

Eu recebo 3 valores por POST: "empresa", "login" e "senha". Crio uma variável `$empresa`, que primeiro é usada no banco `banco-1`. Validações feitas, a mesma variável precisa ser checada no banco `financeiro`. Após um retorno positivo, aí sim eu acesso o banco do sistema e verifico o login e a senha.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
  public function entrar(Request $request){
    $usuario = new \App\usuario();

$login = $request->usuario;
$senha = $request->senha;
$empresa = $request->empresa;
$cliente = DB::connection('banco-1')
->table('clientes')
->select('endereco','banco','nomecompleto','empresa','codigo','cnpj')
->where('empresa', '=',$empresa)->get();
```

Onde `$cliente` não é um model, é apenas uma variável. O Laravel retorna o erro dizendo que a tabela "clientes" não existe no banco "principal", ou seja, o `DB::connection('banco-1')` não conectou no banco-1 mas no principal, e mesmo assim a query rodou.

Segue também como está o arquivo config/database.php (os os dados sensíveis removidos, claro):

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', '-'),

'connections' => [

    'principal' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '-'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '-'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '-'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'banco-1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '-'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '-'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '-'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'financeiro' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '-'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '-'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '-'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

Estou esquecendo de alguma coisa?

Comment: Poste o arquivo de configuração de conexões, acho que sei o que é!

Comment: Se nada mais funcionar, e você só precisar acessar esses dois bancos nesse único lugar, você poderia usar o PDO mesmo (ou um conector de banco de sua preferência) nessas duas queries. Pelo menos até você conseguir resolver pelo Laravel mesmo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu editei para você dar uma olhada.
Daniel obrigado pela dica, vou fazer isso mesmo. Mas queria fazer funcionar corretamente pois preciso desse mesmo esquema funcionando em outros sistemas.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira foi feita uma resposta, você estava usando errado, é por causa disso, outra coisa no próprio Eloquent se pode mudar para ficar mais fácil, evite usar isso no Controller, só no último caso mesmo ... A resposta explica como solucionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando errado por isso que a configuração é a mesma nas 3 conexões, onde a `helper` (***função***) `env` está buscando na mesma chave as configurações do banco, usuário e senha.

### Correções:

***Arquivo*** `config/database.php`

Foi adicionado na `banco-1` com as configurações do `.env` o número 1 na frente da configuração, exemplo:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE1', '-'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME1', '-'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD1', '-'),
```

Também na `financeiro` com as configurações do `.env` o número 2 na frente da configuração, exemplo:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', '-'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', '-'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', '-'),
```

***Arquivo completo:***

---

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', '-'),

'connections' => [

    'principal' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '-'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '-'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '-'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'banco-1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE1', '-'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME1', '-'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD1', '-'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'financeiro' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', '-'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', '-'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', '-'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

***Observação:*** aonde está o **-** (**traço**), é o valor padrão da configuração que só será usado se não for encontrado o valor da primeira configuração.

No arquivo `.env` que está na raiz do seu projeto adicione essas configurações como exemplo abaixo:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xwuxK/b2WGIUpNb73qJgbF8H3T94YqH6aDBldhECSiw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=senha

DB_DATABASE1=nome_do_banco
DB_USERNAME1=nome_do_usuario
DB_PASSWORD1=senha_do_banco

DB_DATABASE2=nome_do_banco
DB_USERNAME2=nome_do_usuario
DB_PASSWORD2=senha_do_banco
    
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

claro que você vai preencher os valores com as configurações respectivas de conexão do seu banco, exatamente aonde estão **nome_do_banco**, **nome_do_usuario** e **senha_do_banco**.

---

***Jeito direto:***

Mude os valores sem o `helper` `.env`:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', '-'),

'connections' => [

    'principal' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '-'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '-'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '-'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'banco-1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'nome_do_banco',
        'username' => 'nome_do_usuario',
        'password' => 'senha_do_banco',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'financeiro' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '-'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'nome_do_banco',
        'username' => 'nome_do_usuario',
        'password' => 'senha_do_banco',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

observe que agora a configuração e direta no `config/database.php` sem a utilização da função `env`. É só alterar os valores aonde está 'nome_do_banco', 'nome_do_usuario' e 'senha_do_banco' nas duas configurações criadas.

Lembrando que eu só estipulei 3 configurações nada impede que seja feita em todas das duas formas.

*Eu prefiro a primeira, dá um pouco de trabalho, mas, acredito que fica em um local apropriado e criado pelo [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) para o carregamento de configurações desse tipo.*

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Environment Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration)
- [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)
- [Defining Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models)

Comment: Você tinha razão, era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Como ficaria isto para 100 clientes ?

Comment: @MikeOtharan ficaria 100 configurações. Apesar de não ter o contexto explicito basicamente é isso.

Comment: Mas é correto fazer isto ? Não há outro método ? Pois se me minha empresa atingir 10000 clientes o código ficara pesado.

Comment: @MikeOtharan o seu comentário deveria ser feito uma pergunta colocando todos os pontos pertinentes para um aumento infinito de configurações. Em comentários eu diria que falta um contexto, falta explicação sua para um aumento do tipo que claramente é inviável, então faça uma pergunta bem explicado do que deseja fazer.

Comment: Eu até fiz uma pergunta sobre isto aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536223/one-database-or-several